# How can i read response after submission of form in node js

Tags: node.js, forms, express, axios, multipartform-data

helper.js

```
exports.instaToken = async (code) => {}
 const formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('client_id', KEY_ID);
 formData.append('client_secret', KEY_SECRET);
 formData.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
 formData.append('redirect_uri', REDIRECT_URI);
 formData.append('code', code);
 let response = formData.submit('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token', function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {console.log(err)};
     console.log(body);
     // console.log(res.resume());
     console.log(res.statusMessage);
     console.log(res.statusCode);
    return res;
 });
```

index.js

```
router.get('/token', async (req, res, next) => {
try {
    let token = 'AQD-uIrveubzTktAysHM7yjSJvqJUueUU9B6r-hhfMer63-uUqSIldjuAyA-fdlm1DICbT9SsR06hWj78hWlAS4Xs--Sq3tyIAZPyIl2Xu72EiMF1WKyh1Jzf1eLUMsQsoHsJFYyjx-RP1pYXOporQrLmI2mRknSkbc3xJIKaXwbnYlonTTSW3B5pJ0n8qDS5jSwoM7gKFl7rTNPAGPd745pY44T18Npkz2UWBCVb_ebNA';
    let response = await instaHelper.instaToken(token);
    req.data = response;
    req.status = 200;
    req.message = 'Token Fetched Successfully';
    next();
}
catch (e) {
    req.status = 400;
    next(e);
 };
});
```

I want to get response after submission of form but response is coming after hitting API and there is something buffer returning after in response but I want response to be returned which is coming after submission of form. Any help will be apricated.

Comment: What is `formData.submit`?

Comment: formData.submit is a function according to formData docs

Comment: Can you link the docs that show that?  The method doesn't exist in browser or node JavaScript and isn't mentioned in MDN docs